# Alert won't fire, jquery form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

i was creating a form validator,but the alert does not fire.
here is the block of code...
edit: i have placed the . before submit and yes i have included the script in the beginning...

```
<form id="validationForm">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input id="email" type="email" /> <br>
    <label for="Telephone">Telephone</label>
    <input id="Telephone" type="number" /><br> 
    <label for="Password">Password</label>
    <input id="Password" type="Password" /><br>
    <label for="ConfirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
    <input id="ConfirmPassword" type="Password" /><br>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Done" />
</form>

</div>
<script>
$("#validationForm").submit(function(event) {
    alert("working");
});

</script>
```

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: Shouldnt there be a dot after the selector? so $("#validationForm").submit(function(event) {

Comment: no.. not in chrome..but ie shows Webpage error details


Message: Expected ';'
Line: 54
Char: 22
Code: 0

which i think is not significant as it always shows something like this when something else is the problem.

Comment: even after placing '.' it is still not working :(

Comment: Well wouldnt it be a good idea even if its not mandatory in Chrome to include it in the event  that another browser requires it?

Comment: @RishabhMaheshwari So you are obviously debugging it wrongly because it should have syntax error in first place. Do you clear browser cache between each attempt?

Comment: i cleared the cache... but same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#validationForm").submit(function(event) {
    alert("working");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="validationForm">
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input id="email" type="email" />
  <br>
  <label for="Telephone">Telephone</label>
  <input id="Telephone" type="number" />
  <br>
  <label for="Password">Password</label>
  <input id="Password" type="Password" />
  <br>
  <label for="ConfirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
  <input id="ConfirmPassword" type="Password" />
  <br>
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Done" />
</form>

</div>
```

You have missed the dot mark before submit().

Comment: i included the script in the beginning <script type="javascript/text" src="jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @RishabhMaheshwari: I did not get you. what the issue, my code not working?

Comment: can u please Post your code With u r References in head tag

Comment: it worked the problem was with me including jquery 2.1.3 when using your link i included 2.1.1 it worked ;)

Answer (score 2):

A typo, a dot should be used while accessing a property from a normal object

```
$("#validationForm").submit(function(event) {
--------------------^
    alert("working");
});
```

Comment: @RishabhMaheshwari Is there any error displaying in console?

Comment: @RishabhMaheshwari Have you included Jquery to your HTML?

Comment: Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)
Timestamp: Tue, 27 Jan 2015 10:38:04 UTC


Message: Object expected
Line: 54
Char: 1
Code: 0

Comment: yes in the beginning <script type="javascript/text" src="jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: What version of JQuery are you using? If you are using an older version the submit button may require more less arguments. Check here http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: @RishabhMaheshwari Did you verify the changes reflected with the loaded code? in source tab??

Comment: @KyleT i am using 2.1.3

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy yes i did.

Answer (score 0):

the . (dot) before the submit is missing just place it every thing will work just fine

```
$("#validationForm").submit(function(event) {
    alert("working");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is dot missing in code.

```
<script>
$("#validationForm").submit(function(event) {
    alert("working");
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Check your JQuery version. Depending on the versions you can have
>   different syntax.

**Also**

Add a dot and the prevent default method to your code like this:

```
$("#validationForm").submit(function(event) 
{
    alert("working");
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0apwuL19/)

Comment: Check Wether Jquery is Loading or Not

Comment: Open page source and ensure that a JQuery reference is included in your HTML head tags.

Comment: can u please Post your code With u r References in head tag

Comment: @KyleT  the problem was i was including jquery 2.1.3 it worked when i included 2.1.1 ... is there a different syntax for 2.1.3?

Comment: @RishabhMaheshwari Well 2.1.3 was only released in December last year ( last month ) so its possible there are still a few bugs. I cant see any changes from doing a quick Google. I recommend sticking with 2.1.1 for the meantime :) Glad you got it sorted

Comment: @KyleT yeah i will, anyways thankyou for helping me out.